# Matching non-digit at the end of a line, and ignore whitespace(s)

Tags: regex, emacs

In  emacs, I want to match a non-digit character which is at the end of a line, except that there may be a sequence of whitespaces between the character and the end of line.
My regex is `[^[:digit:] ] *$` with `M-x occur` , but it will matches

```
An Application: Quilting / 15
```

followed by a blank line.

Why am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding line break characters to the regex pattern, in the `[^..]` group? You can enter a newline character using `C-o`, `C-q C-j`, or `C-q 012 RET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^...]` matches a new line character. So, add it to the `[^...]` group by pressing `C-o`.

```
(search-forward-regexp "[^[:digit:]
 ] *$")
```

Here is an example with `search-forward-regexp` used for a quick test:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your request but try this pattern

```
([^[:digit:] ]+)(?= *$)
```